# How to estimate the area required by first responders with a stretcher?

Tags: emergency-preparedness, measurement

I am editing a book about taking care of elderly people.

Imagine the charge (person that is being taken care of) lives in a room sketched below and spends most of their time in the bed.

[image: Sketch of the room]

In case of an emergency, first responders must get from the entrance into the room, put the charge on a strechter, and carry them out (arrows from the entrance to the room and backwards).

How can I estimate

- how wide the hallway must be (Y in the drawing) and
- at what distance from the wall the bed must be located (X in the drawing)

so that first responders can get in and out of the room with a stretcher (incl. the room that is required when you turn the stretcher when carrying out the charge)?

Comment: That sounds like a question for your fire marshal. Code may have something to say about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it 's not about home improvement and could possibly have legal  ramifications.

Comment: If this is a room & hall in that person’s house then you get what is there. However, if it is an hotel or old person’s residence then it has to meet standards in most countries which means you have to check the standards for your country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no code requirement for width of hallways in residences.

However, the minimum width for hospitals is 6’. This is primarily so gurneys can pass. (Btw, ER gurneys are much bigger than ambulance gurneys.)

The commercial code (not residential houses) require a doorway to be a minimum of 32” clear opening when the door is in the “open” position. If you add 2” for the door to project into the clear opening AND add 1/2” on each side of the doorway for the “stop”, then the minimum width door is 35” wide, but 36” is a standard width and makes it slightly easier for the wheelchair to pass through the doorway.

When we layout bedrooms, we leave about 2’ from the bed to the wall. This is for a nightstand and for ease of making the bed...which I think would be good for the caretaker too.

Also, remember that EMT’s get people out of bathrooms, etc. so they’ll get them in an emergency.